# PandasQueryEngine from llama-index is unable to execute code with the following error: invalid syntax (, line 0)

Tags: pandas, large-language-model, llama-index, llama-cpp-python

I have the following code. I am trying to use the local llama2-chat-13B model. The instructions appear to be good but the final output is erroring out.

```
import logging
import sys
from IPython.display import Markdown, display

import pandas as pd
from llama_index.query_engine import PandasQueryEngine

df = pd.read_csv('./data/test.csv')
df.head()

service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(llm="local", embed_model="local")

query_engine = PandasQueryEngine(df=df, verbose=True, service_context=service_context)

response = query_engine.query("What is the size of the dataframe")
display(Markdown(f"<b>{response}</b>"))
```

Here is the output:

```
> Pandas Instructions:
```

Sure, I'd be happy to help! Based on the input query "What is the size of the dataframe?", we can create an executable Python code using Pandas as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd

df_size = len(df)
```

This code will give us the size of the dataframe, which is the number of rows it contains. The `len()` function returns the length of a list or an array, and in this case, it returns the number of rows in the dataframe.

Note that we don't need to use quotes around the variable name `df` because it is already defined as a pandas DataFrame object. Also, the `eval()` function is not necessary here since we are only executing a simple Python expression.

```
> Pandas Output: There was an error running the output as Python code. Error message: unexpected indent (<unknown>, line 1)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/envs/llm/lib/python3.11/site-packages/llama_index/query_engine/pandas_query_engine.py", line 60, in default_output_processor
    tree = ast.parse(output)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/conda/envs/llm/lib/python3.11/ast.py", line 50, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, flags,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    Sure, I'd be happy to help! Based on the input query "What is the size of the dataframe?", we can create an executable Python code using Pandas as follows:
IndentationError: unexpected indent
llama_print_timings:        load time =    3552.20 ms
llama_print_timings:      sample time =      95.95 ms /   165 runs   (    0.58 ms per token,  1719.63 tokens per second)
llama_print_timings: prompt eval time =       0.00 ms /     1 tokens (    0.00 ms per token,      inf tokens per second)
llama_print_timings:        eval time =   24428.80 ms /   165 runs   (  148.05 ms per token,     6.75 tokens per second)
llama_print_timings:       total time =   24965.81 ms
There was an error running the output as Python code. Error message: unexpected indent (, line 1)
```

Could this be because I am not using OpenAI? Any leads on resolving this are appreciated. Are there any  alternatives to PandasQueryEngine which can be used with any model of my choice to analyze a dataframe using natural language?

I tried the above code and was expecting it to print the df_size as Pandas Output.

Answer (score -1):

I have a work around for this. Instead of Pandas Query engine, which throws a lot of error. You can use Pandas AI or you can import your csv data to sqllite db and use SQL Engine